pyzmq package stopped installing in imx6ul based single board computer
Issue description
pip3 install pyzmq==22.0.3 or pip3 install pyzmq does not install this package anymore on imx6ul based single board computer
Environment
Hardware: NXP imx6ul (https://www.phytec.com/product/phycore-imx6ul/)
OS
Yocto distribution based on https://www.phytec.eu/en/bsp-download/?bsp=BSP-Yocto-Ampliphy-i.MX6UL-PD21.2.1
NOTE1: On desktop distros, installation is still fine.
NOTE2: This problem occurred only yesterday. All the previous days it was installing fine.
What's the actual result?

Attached all possible trials to rectify error here -
pyzmqerror.txt
Removed other packages which are required for our application (python-string-utils jsonschema websockets websocket-client schedule aiofiles ocpp) and tried installing only pyzmq. Did not work.

I know that this particular hardware will be unavailable for you guys to test.
Please take help of logs and let me know if this can be solved.
Thanks!

"error: command 'arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-g++' failed: No such file or directory" Is the compiler installed?

That is the problem here, it never asked for compiler before. We cross compile C/C++ application in the yocto toolchain and then we transfer binaries to board via scp. And for Python, we just scp .py files and run them on the board without any issue. We need to install python packages before running our main .py file and all the packages I mentioned above used to install without any issues. This is the first time we see it asking for a compiler. As per your comment I checked for a file like that and found "/usr/bin/arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-cpp" but this one can't compile simple helloworld.c.

As @phd commented, it was a compiler-not-found error.
Since this is an embedded computer, OS is very minimal (~160MB) has no compiler in it. Cross compilation is the only method. For that we had to include a line in yocto/build/layer.conf file
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-pyzmq"

After recompiling the image with bitbake, pyzmq was available readily to use.
Mistake we did is not observing this behaviour previously.
